# How to compose styling with sass and css-modules?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, css-modules

I just go into `create-react-app v2` and I was wondering how the styling is done in projects. There are so many ways to do styling. For instance, if you have `.NavBar` which also uses a reuseable `.container` and maybe another class, how do you compose them together? Do you use `:root` and use `compose` of css-modules or do you use `@extend` or `@mixins` of sass? Or maybe pass an array as className `<div className={['navbar', 'container']}>`?

How do you do the importing as well? Is importing one `index.scss` file containing all re-useable classes for each `[name].module.scss` the way to go?

So every [name].module.scss starts like this:

```
@import '../../styles/index.scss"

....
.navbar {
display: flex;
}
....
```

and index.scss has

```
@import 'layout'
@import 'colors'
@import 'typography'
...
```

Comment: there are two good video by Elijah Manor. 
check these out it may help you.
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-css-modules-with-create-react-app-2-0
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-add-sass-support-to-create-react-app-2-0